# Python is there a difference calling a method from super, or from the class

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

Using Django I am in the habit of overriding methods in generic views using super:

```
class MyClass(SomeGenericView):

    def method_to_override(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something extra here  

        return super(MyClass, self).method_to_override(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I notice that pydev autocompletes calling the method from the parent class instead:

```
class MyClass(SomeGenericView):

    def method_to_override(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something extra here  

        return SomeGenericView.method_to_override(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Is there any difference between these approaches? Is any one preferred for any reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're dealing with old-style classes (which is not the case here), using `super()` is the RightThing(tm) to do, as `super()` will properly take care of calling the right "next" method according to inheritance graph - remember, Python does support multiple inheritance (which FWIW is widely used in Django's class-based views).

Comment: Yes, that was pointed out to me, I have updated the question.

Comment: @wobbily_col: edited my answer accordingly. The answer is the same anyway: unless you have to deal with legacy code relying on old-style classes, always use  `super()`.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken the second example would cause an infinite loop, since it's a recursive call without any stop criteria.

I think it should replace with the name of the parent class, but even then there are going to be some differences when you subclass `MyClass`.

In the first example, the subclass will call the method in `MyClass`, which is the parent, while in the second it will call the method in `SomeGenericView`, since it's hardcoded.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I typed that out incorrectly. I have updated the question now.

Comment: Well, my answer holds. Both approaches are the same unless you're subclassing MyClass. If you subclass it, usually using `super` is preffered, but it depends on the expected bahaviour when you subclass. Do you always want the SomeGenericView method to be called as is the case in the second example, or do you want the method from the parent class to be called as is the case in the first example. That's what you have to ask yourself when chooseing between the two options.

Comment: "In the first example, the subclass will call the method in MyClass, which is the parent," that doesn't make much sense. It calls the method on the parent class - which is in SomeGenericView, so effectively the same, which is why I asked the question.